# jQuery can't encode a parameter which is a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I have a GET request that takes a parameter, this parameter is also a URL. So normally I just encode the URL and then decode it in my server, this works pefectly from Java, but now I am on jQuery and I have a problem with it.

This is the value of that parameter:

> http://www.BookOntology.com/bo#ania

When I encode it like this:

```
encodeURI(userURI)
```

I get the same value, while i thought that i should have gotten this

> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.BookOntology.com%2Fbo%23ania

#### To show you what is the wrong

My current approach (which is using econdeURI) brings this final URL (note that I just want to encode the paramter not the whole URL).

> http://bla bla bla?userURI=http://www.BookOntology.com/bo#ania

But in the server when i read the value of the userURI parameter i get:

> http://www.BookOntology.com/bo

It is definitely a problem with the way i encode that value of that parameter because, again, the value after and before encoding is the same though the value contains some characters that should be changed.

Could you help me pass that please?

Comment: Try to use this and try .encodeURIComponent

Comment: @user4246662 what's that plz ? a function ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: Discover [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: @user4246662 it works, plz write an answer thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `encodeURIComponent` function , which encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)

DEMO: [encode input value](https://jsfiddle.net/b36kktpd/5/)

Read the [MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`encodeURI` only changes characters that can't appear in a URL at all.

You're looking for `encodeURIComponent` which encodes all characters with special meaning in a URL as well (and makes it suitable for inserting in a query string).